# Not able to Pause Spring Kafka Container

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to pause the Kafka Listener.

1. I call http://localhost:8080/pause to the pause the container
2. I send data on the  topic.
3. Consumer starts consuming the message

I expected that consumer would be paused but message is still being read from Kafka topic.
How can i pause the consumer?
I am using 2.5.0 (Spring Boot Parent)

```
     @KafkaListener(id="foo" ,topics = "mytopic-3", concurrency = "3", groupId = "mytopic-1-groupid")
        

@Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
        
          @GetMapping("/pause")
            public void pause(  )
            {
                
                System.out.println(" Pausing Kafka Listener");
                kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("foo").pause();
            }
         
        
          @Configuration
    @EnableKafka
    public class KafkaConsumerConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {
        
        
        @Autowired
        private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;
        
       
        @Override
        public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
              registrar.setValidator(this.validator);
            
        }
```

Comment: What version are you using? We just fixed a bug in 2.7.x ([today](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1868)) where the pause is performed but then immediately resumed. With earlier versions (and after the fix), the pause won't take effect until all the records from the previous poll are processed. Set `max.poll.records=1` if you want the pause to take immediate effect.

Comment: Use the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(id) method to get a reference to the container.

Cast it to a ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer and call getContainers() to get a list of the child KafkaMessageListenerContainers; you can then pause/resume them individually

Comment: @Gary Russell wouldn't that be the answer?

Comment: He is using concurrency="3"

Comment: i added one more line `message `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("foo").isContainerPaused()`.It returns `false` when i call the rest end point to pause it for first time but return `true` for the second time .Even after setting poll record=1 i can still see message being consumed

Comment: @GaryRussell i have added the version in my question.Let me know which version i can use

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in all 2.7.x versions. Boot 2.5 (currently 2.5.2) pulls in 2.7.x; next week's 2.5.3 release should have the fix (spring-kafka 2.7.4).  The fix is in a snapshot 2.7.4-SNAPSHOT which you can get by adding the https://repo.spring.io/snapshots to your build config. `2.7.4` should be available on Monday (and boot 2.5.3 later in the week). You could also temporarily downgrade to 2.6.9 (spring-kafka). @RanLupovich no; pausing the concurrent container will pause all the child containers.

Comment: @GaryRussell  i need to implement this in PROD in few months.Thanks for fixing it .Just 1 last question I have multiple kafka listeners.And some kafka listener have multiple topics with concurrency > 1.So doing pause for particular id will pause consuming  for all topics?And same if we do resume it will resume for all topics for that "id".

Comment: The snapshot repo is https://repo.spring.io/snapshot (no s). Correct; all topics/partitions are paused/resumed when you pause/resume the container.  However, 2.7 added the ability to pause individual `TopicPartition`s (via `pausePartition()` and `resumePartition()` (this is what broke the container pause).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in all 2.7.x versions. Fixed [today](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1868) where the container is immediately resumed after pausing.

Boot 2.5 (currently 2.5.2) pulls in 2.7.x; next week's 2.5.3 release should have the fix (spring-kafka 2.7.4).

The fix is in a snapshot 2.7.4-SNAPSHOT which you can get by adding the https://repo.spring.io/snapshot to your build config.

`2.7.4` should be available on Monday (and boot 2.5.3 later in the week).

You could also tenporarily downgrade to 2.6.9 (spring-kafka).